# Is it secure to run public ethereum node?

Tags: security, ethereum, web3js, truffle, metamask

I'm creating my first Ethereum contract with truffle. I want the web application to be usable without MetaMask so I was wondering if it is a good idea to run my own private node and to
connect from the frontend like this:

```
this.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://my-public-ip:8545'));
```

Are there any security risks with this approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how I did it, but it allows bots to steal the ether from these accounts:

1. I did setup publicly accessible node like this:

   ```
   geth  --mine  --nodiscover  --maxpeers 0  --networkid 1  --rpc  --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddr "my-public-ip" --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3"
   ```
2. I created a new Ethereum account that is going to be my "contract owner" account
3. I transferred a small amount of ether into the "contract owner" account so I would have enough gas to deploy my new contract
4. I did `setup truffle` to connect to my Ethereum node
5. I used truffle console to unlock my account
6. I got the error "*Error: exceeds block gas limit*"

At this point I was confused, because I saw that on etherscan I have about 10USD worth of ether in my account. That should be enough to deploy my contract.

I checked etherscan again, and I saw "outgoing" transactions draining all my money from the Ethereum address. This is how the money was stolen:

1. A bot found out about my public Ethereum node
2. It connected to it and requested the account list + account balances
3. It started sending `sendTransaction` requests non stop
4. When I unlocked my account on the public node to deploy my contract - the bot that was using the same node also got access to my account and it transferred the funds from my account

Comment: I'm not sure of the value of an answer that says "here's how to do it in an unsecure way", let alone the value of such an answer on a question asking how to do it in a _secure_ way.